# Why do the impression counts on the AdSense app and on the site apps.AdMob.com differ?

Tags: adsense, admob

I am using admob in my app to show advertising. To check the impressions I am using AdSense app and set with my AdMob account.

When I check the impressions count on site [apps.admob.com](http://apps.admob.com/?hl=en#home) and on app AdSense impression count differ. Its almost double on AdSense app. What is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same behavior.

Adsense report:
[image: Adsense report]

Admob report:
[image: Admob report]

It seems that Admob shows adsense when it has no admob ads to show. but still it is a mystery tome why this is not indicated explicitly in the Admob website.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference what Adsense calls impressions Admob calls it Requests. Adsense impression is counted for each ad request where at least one ad has begun to download to the user's device. But Adsence doesn't know if the ad really shows. In the other hand Admob knows when ads have been shown, and it is call Admob impression.